# Progressbar of a bin file loading

Tags: java, swing, loading, bin

how can I show a JProgressBar component like on the loading of a bin file?

I can only found solutions for iterative bin read and I'm using an object reading like:

```
CustomObj test = (CustomObj) in.readObject();
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you can't measure the progress of the process, then you can only specify the "indeterminate mode" of the progress bar.  When in this mode, the progress bar will indicate that it is working, but the completion of the process is unknown.

```
JProgressBar progress = new JProgressBar();
progress.setIndeterminate(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Subclass [`java.io.FilteredInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) to count the number of bytes being read and insert it between your `ObjectInputStream` and the underlying `InputStream` being read.

You can update the progress bar by sampling the running count or using a callback built in to your subclass.

Example:

```
public class CountingInputStream extends FilteredInputStream {

    private int numBytes;

    public CountingInputStream(InputStream inputStream){
        this(inputStream);
    }

    public int getNumBytes(){
        return numBytes;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() {
        int b = super.read();
        if(b != -1){
            countBytes(1);
        }
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b){
        int n = super.read(b);
        if(n >= 0){
           countBytes(n);
        }
        return n;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len){
        int n = super.read(b, off, len);
        if(n >= 0){
           countBytes(n);
        }
        return n;
    }    

    private void countBytes(int n){
        numBytes += n;
    }

}
```

It could be used like below (assume `InputStream is` your source of data).:

```
InputStream is = ...;
CountingInputStream cis = new CountingInputStream(is)
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(cis);

ois.readObject();
```

You can sample `cis.getNumBytes()` from a different thread (potentially with a Swing timer) and use the returned value to update a `JProgressBar`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to do two things:

1. Creating a wrapping class around your original inputstream so that you can monitor the bytes that are read from it. Basically, you extends `InputStream` and delegate everything to the original stream (except a few methods) and in the read() method, you make sure that you notify some listener.
2. I guess that if you want a progress bar, it means that the loading operation takes a while and you want to provide feedback to the user. Long running task cannot run directly on the EDT (so typically, you cannot perform your task in an `actionPerformed` method). You therefore need to delegate the work to another Thread, by using a SwingWorker for example. If you don't this, then the UI will freeze and the feedback will not be viewable by the user.

This being, said it may seem complex or not trivial. Therefore, here some short example, that illustrates all this and works:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class TestProgressBar {

    // Some simple listener interface to get a callback as bytes are being read
    public static interface ProgressListener {
        public void notifyByteRead();
    }

    // The wrapping input stream that will call the listener as bytes are being read
    public static class ProgressInputStream extends InputStream {

        private InputStream in;

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            int read = in.read();
            if (read > -1) {
                // Here we notify the listener
                listener.notifyByteRead();
            }
            return read;
        }

        @Override
        public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
            return in.skip(n);
        }

        @Override
        public int available() throws IOException {
            return in.available();
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            in.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void mark(int readlimit) {
            in.mark(readlimit);
        }

        @Override
        public void reset() throws IOException {
            in.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean markSupported() {
            return in.markSupported();
        }

        private ProgressListener listener;

        public ProgressInputStream(InputStream in, ProgressListener listener) {
            this.in = in;
            this.listener = listener;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                init();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void init() {
        // 1. Let's create a big object with lots of data
        List<Long> object = new ArrayList<Long>();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
            object.add(random.nextLong());
        }

        // 2. We write it to a temp file
        File tempFile = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try {
            tempFile = File.createTempFile("Test", ".bin");
            tempFile.deleteOnExit();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos));
            oos.writeObject(object);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (oos != null) {
                    oos.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        if (tempFile == null) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        // 3. Now let's build a UI to load that
        final File theFile = tempFile;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test ghost text");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        final JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar(0, (int) tempFile.length());
        JButton button = new JButton("load");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                bar.setValue(0);
                // Declare and implement a Swing worker that will run in another thread
                SwingWorker<Void, Integer> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
                        // Here we are on the EDT, so we can safely notify the progressbar
                        super.process(chunks);
                        bar.setValue(bar.getValue() + chunks.size());
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        // Here we are not in the EDT, we perform the task but don't modify anything in the UI
                        ProgressInputStream pis = new ProgressInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(theFile)),
                                new ProgressListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void notifyByteRead() {
                                        publish(1); // the value that is sent here could be anything, we don't use it.
                                    }
                                });
                        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(pis);
                        try {
                            List<Long> readObject = (List<Long>) ois.readObject();
                            System.err.println("Loaded " + readObject.size() + " long values");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            pis.close();
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                };
                // Start the worker
                worker.execute();
            }
        });
        panel.add(bar);
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will take a look on that, thank you very much for the answer.. 

The loading may be long or not,

There is nothing that I can use on outputing objects to bin using a progressbar too?

Cheers

Comment: @user3738319 just use the same principles by extending OutputStream.